# How do I check to see if an object respond_to? MyObject#attr_reader :my_property but not setter

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming

I am writing some tests for a ruby gem...

How do I check to see if an object respond_to? MyObject#attr_reader :my_property but not MyObject#attr_writer :my_property or MyObject#my_property(value) # <= setter?

Plenty of examples simply checking everything but.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`attr_reader :my_property` is essentially syntactic sugar for

```
def my_property
  @my_property
end
```

likewise, `attr_writer :my_property` is shorthand for

```
def my_property=(val)
  @my_property = val
end
```

Note that the method defined by `attr_writer` ends with and equals sign; This means that  `obj.my_property = foo` is interpreted as `obj.my_property=(foo)`; this is how setters are defined in ruby, while getters are simply methods which take no parameters and return a value.

So, back to the original question. If `obj.respond_to? :my_property` returns true, that means its getter is set. (Note that as getters are just ordinary methods, you can't tell for certain whether the method is actually a getter or some completely unrelated method) Likewise if `obj.respond_to? :my_property=` returns true, that means the setter method is set.

Answer (score 2):

Check for getter: 
**my_object.respond_to? :the_property**

Check for setter: 
**my_object.respond_to? :the_property=**